# Cannot Build v8go v0.9.0 in Docker

Tags: c++, docker, go, gcc, v8

The author of the popular [v8go](https://github.com/rogchap/v8go) library is not responsive and [this issue](https://github.com/rogchap/v8go/issues/381) is very pressing for me.

---

It looks like the version of GCC that ships with the official Golang Dcoker containers is too old to work with v0.9.0. I'm getting errors from a Dockerfile that worked with `v0.8.0` like this.

```
undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental

# Builder base image
FROM golang:1.20.1 as builder

# Set a directory to work from
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/foo/bar

# Install dependencies
RUN dpkg --add-architecture amd64 \
    && apt-get upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu g++-x86-64-linux-gnu

# Copy everything in and compile
# There may be cache optimizations we can make
COPY . .

# Some of our dependencies are private, so we need to use SSH to clone them.
RUN git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts


# Build our binary.
RUN --mount=type=ssh GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc CXX=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ make build-go EXTRA_LD_FLAGS="-s -w -extldflags '-dynamic'"
```